# custom allocator - microsoft std::map implementation deallocates the same element twice, gcc works fine

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory-management

The idea was to have a reusable stl-compatible allocator that is simple to use and won't use the free-store in performance-critical areas of the software.

Here's some test code (very basic testing):

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

#include "CustomPoolAllocator.h"

typedef std::map<int, int>::value_type mymap_vtype;
typedef CustomPoolAllocator<mymap_vtype, 200> my_alloc_type;

int main()
{
    std::map<int, int, std::less<int>, my_alloc_type> mymap;

    int sign = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 90; ++i)
    {
        mymap[i * sign] = i;
        sign *= -1;
    }

    for (auto & elem : mymap)
        std::cout << elem.first << " " << elem.second << std::endl;

    mymap.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < 90; ++i)
    {
        mymap[i * sign] = i;
        sign *= -1;
    }

    for (auto & elem : mymap)
        std::cout << elem.first << " " << elem.second << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Looks like this testing is enough to find some problems though.
I tested using both MinGW and Visual-Studio 2013.

Not sure it's very important, but here's what `g++ --version` prints:

> g++ (x86_64-posix-seh-rev1, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 4.9.2
>   Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc. This is free
>   software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
>   warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
>   PURPOSE.

**In Visual-Studio**, consistently adding the first 23 elements to the map it works well.

After adding the 24th element to the map, there's a deallocation of an element (not clear to me why) and then the same address is immediately deallocated again (verified with breakpoints, step-by-step debugging).

And of course, the program reaches the `abort()` and prints:

> SingleSizeAlloc: out of range Element or deallocated twice! index: 24, elements in pool: 200, element size: 24

If I remove the abort(), There's some exception that I don't understand:
`std::length_error`

**When built with MinGW, it worked as expected without issues.**

Can someone please help me understand what's going on?
Many thanks!

The code for the reusable allocator template is here:

```
#ifndef _CustomPoolAllocator_H_
#define _CustomPoolAllocator_H_

#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>

// This is a very simple fixed-size block allocator based on a free-list.
class SingleSizeAlloc
{
    size_t size;
    const size_t num;
    const size_t num_illegal;
    char *buf;
    size_t listHead;
    size_t *list;
public:
    SingleSizeAlloc(size_t s, size_t n) :
            size(s), num(n), num_illegal(n + 1)
    {
        buf = new char[size * num];
        list = new size_t[num];
        listHead = 0;
        for (unsigned i = 0, j = 1; i < n; ++i, ++j)
        {
            list[i] = j;
        }
    }

    ~SingleSizeAlloc()
    {
        delete[] buf;
        delete[] list;
        listHead = 0;
        list = 0;
    }

    size_t getSize() const
    {
        return size;
    }

    void *allocate()
    {
        void *allocated = NULL;
        if (listHead == num)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "SingleSizeAlloc: ERROR - no memory left!\n");
            abort();
        }
        else
        {
            size_t idx = listHead;
            if (num_illegal == list[idx])
            {
                fprintf(stderr,
                        "SingleSizeAlloc: ERROR - allocated same element twice! idx: %u, size: %u, num elements in pool: %u\n",
                        (unsigned) idx, (unsigned) size, (unsigned) num);
                abort();
            }
            listHead = list[idx];
            allocated = buf + idx * size;
            list[idx] = num_illegal;
        }
        return allocated;
    }

    void deallocate(void *p)
    {
        size_t index = ((char *) p - buf) / size;
        if (num_illegal == list[index])
        {
            list[index] = listHead;
            listHead = index;
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(stderr,
                    "SingleSizeAlloc: out of range Element or deallocated twice! index: %u, elements in pool: %u, element size: %u\n",
                    (unsigned) index, (unsigned) num, (unsigned) size);
            abort();
        }
    }

};


// Contains up-to 16 simple free-list allocators where each supports a different block size.
// Each related STL-Compatible allcator object will have a pointer to this reference-counted object.
// When the last STL-Compatible allcator object is destroyed, this object will be destroyed too.
class FixedSizeAllocator
{
    enum
    {
        MAX_DIFFERENT_SIZES = 16
    };

    struct IsSize
    {
        size_t s;
        IsSize(size_t s) :
                s(s)
        {
        }
        bool operator()(const SingleSizeAlloc* p) const
        {
            return (s == p->getSize());
        }
    };

    SingleSizeAlloc *pools[MAX_DIFFERENT_SIZES];
    const size_t eachPoolSize;
    int refcounter;
    int numPools;

public:
    FixedSizeAllocator(size_t n) :
            eachPoolSize(n), refcounter(0), numPools(0)
    {
        memset(pools, 0, sizeof(pools));
    }

    ~FixedSizeAllocator()
    {
        SingleSizeAlloc **pp = pools;
        for (int i = 0; i < numPools && *pp; ++i, ++pp)
        {
            delete *pp;
            *pp = 0;
        }
    }

    void incRefCounter()
    {
        refcounter++;
    }
    void decRefCounter()
    {
        refcounter--;
    }
    int getRefCounter() const
    {
        return refcounter;
    }

    void *allocate(size_t s, size_t n)
    {
        if (n > 1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,
                    "FixedSizeAllocator doesn't support allocation of multiple elements (i.e. can't be used for containters such as vector...)");
            abort();
        }
        SingleSizeAlloc **pp = std::find_if(pools, pools + numPools, IsSize(s));
        int idx = pp - pools;
        if (idx >= numPools)
        {
            if (idx < MAX_DIFFERENT_SIZES)
            {
                *pp = new SingleSizeAlloc(s, eachPoolSize);
                numPools++;
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(stderr,
                        "FixedSizeAllocator: ERROR - allocate error !! size: %u, different sizes in the allocator: %d\n",
                        (unsigned) s, idx);
                abort();
            }
        }
        return (*pp)->allocate();
    }

    void deallocate(void *pObj, size_t size)
    {
        SingleSizeAlloc **pp = std::find_if(pools, pools + numPools,
                IsSize(size));
        int idx = pp - pools;
        if (idx >= numPools)
        {
            if (idx >= MAX_DIFFERENT_SIZES)
            {
                fprintf(stderr,
                        "FixedSizeAllocator: ERROR - deallocate error!! size: %u\n",
                        (unsigned) size);
                abort();
            }
        }
        (*pp)->deallocate(pObj);
    }
};

// This is the STL compatible interface. it holds a pointer to the actual implementation of the allocator.
// Whenever this object is created from a related object (see the rebind), the reference counter for the
// allocator is incremented (decremented in d'tor).
// When the last of these is destroyed, the implementation object is also destroyed.
template<class T, size_t pool_size> class CustomPoolAllocator
{
private:
    CustomPoolAllocator &operator=(const CustomPoolAllocator &other);

public:
    typedef size_t size_type;
    typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
    typedef T* pointer;
    typedef const T* const_pointer;
    typedef T& reference;
    typedef const T& const_reference;
    typedef T value_type;
    template<class U> struct rebind
    {
        typedef CustomPoolAllocator<U, pool_size> other;
    };

    FixedSizeAllocator *allocImp;
    CustomPoolAllocator()
    {
        // create a new FixedSizeAllocator
        allocImp = new FixedSizeAllocator(pool_size);
        allocImp->incRefCounter();
    }

    template<class Q>
    CustomPoolAllocator(const CustomPoolAllocator<Q, pool_size>& other)
    {
        allocImp = other.allocImp;
        allocImp->incRefCounter();
    }

    // This copy-c'tor was missing in the original code,
    // it's necessary, otherwise the ref-counter isn't incremented.
    CustomPoolAllocator(const CustomPoolAllocator& other)
    {
        allocImp = other.allocImp;
        allocImp->incRefCounter();
    }

    ~CustomPoolAllocator()
    {
        allocImp->decRefCounter();
        if (0 == allocImp->getRefCounter())
        {
            delete allocImp;
            allocImp = 0;
        }
    }

    pointer address(reference x) const
    {
        return &x;
    }
    const_pointer address(const_reference x) const
    {
        return &x;
    }

    pointer allocate(size_type n)
    {
        return (pointer) allocImp->allocate(sizeof(T), n);
    }

    void deallocate(pointer p, size_type n)
    {
        allocImp->deallocate(p, n * sizeof(T));
    }

    size_type max_size() const
    {
        return sizeof(T); // #### this is the problem!!! should return pool_size.
    }

    void construct(pointer p, const T& val)
    {
        new (p) T(val);
    }
    void destroy(pointer p)
    {
        p->~T();
    }
};

#endif // _CustomPoolAllocator_H_
```

Comment: First, copying `CustomPoolAllocator` doesn't increase the reference count. The implicitly declared copy constructor is used. And why are you writing all the C++03 boilerplate?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Fixed the default copy constructor issue in the original and added a C++11 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been the max_size() member function.

That's where the number 24 came from (24 == sizeof(T)).
It has been pointed out to me by someone here, but I can't trace the source to give credit.

This should have returned the number of elements that the pool can contain (i.e. pool_size in our case).

Also, the comment about the default copy c'tor is very true and warrants editing the original code.

I still find it weird that the container deallocated the same address twice (microsoft bug?)

Either way, thanks everybody!

In addition, here's a fixed version which makes use of C++11 features.
it eliminates the need to implement any destructors and the default copy constructor.

```
#ifndef _CustomPoolAllocator_H_
#define _CustomPoolAllocator_H_

#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>

// This is a very simple fixed-size block allocator based on a free-list.
class SingleSizeAlloc
{
    size_t size;
    const size_t num;
    const size_t num_illegal;
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> buf;
    std::unique_ptr<size_t[]> list;
    size_t listHead;
    size_t * const listEnd;
public:
    SingleSizeAlloc(size_t size, size_t n) :
        size(size), num(n), num_illegal(n + 1), buf(new char[size * num]), list(
        new size_t[num]), listEnd(list.get() + num)
    {
        listHead = 0;
        unsigned i = 0;
        std::for_each(list.get(), listEnd, [&i](size_t &elem)
        {   elem = ++i; });
    }

    ~SingleSizeAlloc()
    {
        listHead = 0;
        list = 0;
    }

    size_t getSize() const
    {
        return size;
    }

    void *allocate()
    {
        void *allocated = NULL;
        if (listHead == num)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "SingleSizeAlloc: ERROR - no memory left!\n");
            abort();
        }
        else
        {
            size_t idx = listHead;
            if (num_illegal == list[idx])
            {
                fprintf(stderr,
                    "SingleSizeAlloc: ERROR - allocated same element twice! idx: %u, size: %u, num elements in pool: %u\n",
                    (unsigned)idx, (unsigned)size, (unsigned)num);
                abort();
            }
            listHead = list[idx];
            allocated = buf.get() + idx * size;
            list[idx] = num_illegal;
        }
        return allocated;
    }

    void deallocate(void *p)
    {
        size_t index = ((char *)p - buf.get()) / size;
        if (num_illegal == list[index])
        {
            list[index] = listHead;
            listHead = index;
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(stderr,
                "SingleSizeAlloc: out of range Element or deallocated twice! index: %u, elements in pool: %u, element size: %u\n",
                (unsigned)index, (unsigned)num, (unsigned)size);
            abort();
        }
    }

};

// Contains up-to 16 simple free-list allocators where each supports a different block size.
// Each related STL-Compatible allcator object will have a pointer to this reference-counted object.
// When the last STL-Compatible allcator object is destroyed, this object will be destroyed too.
class FixedSizeAllocator
{
    enum
    {
        MAX_DIFFERENT_SIZES = 16
    };

    struct IsSize
    {
        size_t size;
        IsSize(size_t size) :
            size(size)
        {
        }
        bool operator()(const std::unique_ptr<SingleSizeAlloc>& p) const
        {
            return (size == p->getSize());
        }
    };

    std::unique_ptr<SingleSizeAlloc> pools[MAX_DIFFERENT_SIZES];
    const size_t eachPoolSize;
    int numPools;

public:
    FixedSizeAllocator(size_t n) :
        eachPoolSize(n), numPools(0)
    {
        memset(pools, 0, sizeof(pools));
    }

    void *allocate(size_t size, size_t n)
    {
        if (n > 1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,
                "FixedSizeAllocator doesn't support allocation of multiple elements (i.e. can't be used for containters such as vector...)");
            abort();
        }
        auto pp = std::find_if(pools, pools + numPools, IsSize(size));
        int idx = pp - pools;
        if (idx >= numPools)
        {
            if (idx < MAX_DIFFERENT_SIZES)
            {
                (*pp).reset(new SingleSizeAlloc(size, eachPoolSize));
                numPools++;
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(stderr,
                    "FixedSizeAllocator: ERROR - allocate error !! size: %u, different sizes in the allocator: %d\n",
                    (unsigned)size, idx);
                abort();
            }
        }
        return (*pp)->allocate();
    }

    void deallocate(void *pObj, size_t size)
    {
        auto pp = std::find_if(pools, pools + numPools, IsSize(size));
        int idx = pp - pools;
        if (idx >= numPools)
        {
            if (idx >= MAX_DIFFERENT_SIZES)
            {
                fprintf(stderr,
                    "FixedSizeAllocator: ERROR - deallocate error ()!! size: %u\n",
                    (unsigned)size);
                abort();
            }
        }
        (*pp)->deallocate(pObj);
    }
};

// This is the STL compatible interface. it holds a pointer to the actual implementation of the allocator.
// Whenever this object is created from a related object (see the rebind), the reference counter for the
// allocator is incremented (decremented in d'tor).
// When the last of these is destroyed, the implementation object is also destroyed.
template<class T, size_t pool_size> class CustomPoolAllocator
{
private:
    CustomPoolAllocator &operator=(const CustomPoolAllocator &other);

public:
    typedef size_t size_type;
    typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
    typedef T* pointer;
    typedef const T* const_pointer;
    typedef T& reference;
    typedef const T& const_reference;
    typedef T value_type;
    template<class U> struct rebind
    {
        typedef CustomPoolAllocator<U, pool_size> other;
    };

    std::shared_ptr<FixedSizeAllocator> allocImp;
    CustomPoolAllocator() :
        allocImp(new FixedSizeAllocator(pool_size))
    {
    }

    template<class Q>
    CustomPoolAllocator(const CustomPoolAllocator<Q, pool_size>& other) :
        allocImp(other.allocImp)
    {
    }

    pointer address(reference x) const
    {
        return &x;
    }
    const_pointer address(const_reference x) const
    {
        return &x;
    }

    pointer allocate(size_type n)
    {
        return (pointer)allocImp->allocate(sizeof(T), n);
    }

    void deallocate(pointer p, size_type n)
    {
        allocImp->deallocate(p, n * sizeof(T));
    }

    size_type max_size() const
    {
        return pool_size;
    }

    void construct(pointer p, const T& val)
    {
        new (p)T(val);
    }
    void destroy(pointer p)
    {
        p->~T();
    }
};

#endif // _CustomPoolAllocator_H_
```

Answer (score 0):

Single size allocator does not look like it copes with

```
A = allocate();
B = allocate();
Free( A );
A = allocate();
C = allocate();
```

I think the head moves, and doesn't cope with being freed and reused.

The difference is likely to be due to optimizations of mingw to reduce copies.

Comment: I just tested this and it seems that it works as intended, I don't think what you wrote is correct.